# Proguard on Android Broken?

Tags: android, ant, obfuscation, proguard

I used to be able to follow the guide [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/proguard-android-and-licensing-server.html) to set up and run Proguard as part of a build, without any problems. However, since updating to the latest version of the ADT tools, I am having trouble. The first problem I run into is:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/myhome/projects/myapp/add-proguard-release.xml:14:
/home/myhome/projects/myapp/${out.classes.dir} does not exist.
```

So I end up having to define ${out.classes.dir} manually in either local.properties or project.properties. Not the end of the world, but a bit of a pain.

The second, more drastic problem is related to external jars. I have a small class in an external jar. When the application launches on a device, the app crashes:

```
11-15 18:35:30.090: E/AndroidRuntime(28258): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mysoftware.informaltimeprovider.InformalTimeProvider
11-15 18:35:30.090: E/AndroidRuntime(28258):    at com.mysoftware.pagemonitor.PrintableTimeProvider.getInformalTime(PrintableTimeProvider.java:14)
```

It is crashing when trying to create an instance of InformalTimeProvider, but judging by the logcat output, this class was not obfuscated, so I don't know why there is a problem.

There is a warning during the build:

```
[proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [/home/myhome/projects/pagemonitor/libs/InformalTimeProvider.jar]
[proguard] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [InformalTimeProvider.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
```

It is just a warning though - I wouldn't expect a crash.

Any help gratefully received.

Barry

Comment: can u tell me how u resplved this manually???

/home/myhome/projects/myapp/${out.classes.dir} does not exist.

Comment: I can't check right now but I've a feeling a gave up on proguard for that particular project :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proguard minimized apps mostly do not work out-of-the-box. In most cases you have to manually specify additional classes that needs to be kept.

In your case I would start by adding the configuration line

```
-keep class com.mysoftware.informaltimeprovider.InformalTimeProvider
```

This explicitly tells proguard that this class is required and can not be removed. If afterwards your app misses another class tell proguard to keep it, too.

Step-by-step you will get closer to a fully working app. I know this try-and-error approach is not nice but optimizing Java Apps is not that simple that it can be fully automated. Especially loading classes by Strings and other run-time related tricks collide with proguard.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I'll have a play with this. Any idea if the manifest warning is anything to worry about?

Comment: This happens because each library has it's own MANIFEST and if you merge all libraries into one proguard doesn't know what to do. Proguard keeps the firt MANIFEST it encounters. Therefore make sure your own JAR file containing the MANIFEST you want to keep is the first in the input jar list.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Couple of questions, how does one make a decision as to which manifest they want to keep? Also, where is the input jar list? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm interested in this warning as well. To your questions: AFAIK external JARs are listed from `libs\ ` directory, no controlled order (search `id="jar.libs.ref"` in C:\Android\tools\ant\build.xml). Android library projects come from the same definition.